# Widehat on one letter

Tags: math-mode, accents

I found this weird behaviour if you apply `\widehat{}` to only one letter. Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\widehat{v}$

\end{document}
```

It produces the following result:

[image: variable v with a hat, but the hat is shifted to the left]

I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 from MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit.

Of course, I want the hat to be on top of the v. What's the problem here? `\widetilde{}`, which is similar, produces correct results even if applied to a single letter.

I don't want to use `\hat{v}`, because here the hat is way narrower and the hat is a function applied to v, not a variable called "hat v". (Unfortunately this seems to be standard in the field in which I'm writing)

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me. Can you show your log?

Comment: The hat comes over the v [if your example is run in texlive 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKJXl.png)

Comment: [My log at pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GkVqt6RS)

Comment: With MikTeX, the hat comes over the `v` too.

Comment: Your version of MikTeX is out of date. The first line of the log should be `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.7) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.8.26)` **You need to update MikTeX**.

Comment: I didn't realize my setup is this old. I'll update and this will probably fix it. (Am I supposed to delete the question now?)

Comment: Present version is 7545.

Comment: @Wauzl first update and see whether that fixes it.

Comment: I updated it, still has the issue. [Here is my log.](https://pastebin.com/hvcY6cTV)

Comment: I got it: It wasn't the fault of TeX, it was a display error of the pdf viewer (pdf-view from the editor Atom). Adobe and the chrome pdf viewer display it correctly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by OP himself.